# If the heat of summer is due to Hell, then why is it winter in the southern hemisphere? And vice versa?

Tags: hadith-interpretation, science

> Narrated Abu Huraira:
>
> The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "In very hot weather delay the Zuhr prayer till
>   it becomes (a bit) cooler because the severity of heat is from the
>   raging of the Hell-fire. The Hell-fire of Hell complained to its Lord
>   saying: O Lord! My parts are eating (destroying) one another. So Allah
>   allowed it to take two breaths, one in the winter and the other in the
>   summer. The breath in the summer is at the time when you feel the
>   severest heat and the breath in the winter is at the time when you
>   feel the severest cold."
>  [Sahih al-Bukhari 536, 537](https://www.sunnah.com/bukhari/9/14)

If the heat of summer is due to Hell, then why is it winter in the southern hemisphere? And vice versa?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I came across this video today by *Sheikh Assim Al Hakeem* on youtube ... coincidence?

[Hell breathes Two breaths in a year (Extreme heat and extreme cold)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oqGvDPuc-z8)

Comment: Can you summarize the video?